# how to implement a single connection string for all .net test projects

Tags: .net, testng, connection-string

So I would, like to know if there is a better solution than the one I currently implement.

The problem:

- I have a solution with multiple test projects.
- Each test project references a single .Common library for managing test data.
- Sometimes it is necessary to use a database to create and or get test data.
- I want all my test projects to use the same server/database when
  dealing with test data.
- If I want to change this service/database I do not want to go to every project to change the connection string in the app.config so I want a single, centralized collection of connection strings to be used by all my test projects

Current solution:

In my .Common project I implement the following

```
        return "Data Source='.'; Initial Catalog='MyData'; Integrated Security='true'";
```

Now I hate hard coding strings and I am frustrated that I cannot put the string into the app.config of my .Common project and reference it directly from the .Common library using:

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Database"].ConnectionString;
```

At run-time the app.config of the currently running test is always referenced, not that of the .Copmmon library (even from within the .Common project).

Maybe I am looking at it from totally the wrong perspective? Maybe for some reason it is better to put this string in every test project? Though personally I cannot see why.

I do not want to share the app.config from my .Common project as each project may have settings that are only relevant to that project and I do not want to put all of these into a single config.

Please if anyone can suggest a better solution to my problem I would be grateful.

### ========== EDIT:

I am hoping to find a wheel that has already been invented.

I understand I could probably code a solution as suggested in the comments and probably in the same time it has taken me to write this post, but I would need to test it and justify it to those above. Also I am not even sure the way I am trying to do this is the correct practice.

Comment: I suggest that you store the connection strings in an xml file and at runtime deserialize the file to a mapped class instance and use the connection strings like that for all projects.

Comment: Yeah, I guess this is the most obvious, I thought about just including the app.config as a resource and doing exactly that but  I was hoping the wheel had already been invented. 
To actually implement something that would need testing is difficult to justify to my boss for a single instance. perhaps if I come across this problem again then I could argue the case.